# Sharepoint 2010 CMIS Integration

Tags: sharepoint-2010, liferay-6, cmis

I have been trying to connect Liferay 6.2 EE with Sharepoint 2010 using CMIS. But failing.
Steps I followed -

1) Install the Sharepoint Connector

2) Created a user which is common in both sharepoint and liferay

3) Activate Sharepoint as a CMIS Producer

4) Added a repository with these details -

```
 Repository Type - Sharepoint
  Site URL - http://<domain>/_vti_bin/cmis/rest/<repo id>?getRepositoryInfo
  Library Name - <repo id>
```

I am able to create repository but no documents and folders are being fetched. Backend error -

```
AxisFault
 faultCode: {http://xml.apache.org/axis/}HTTP
 faultSubcode:
 faultString: (405)The service method invoked requires an optional capability not supported by the repository.
 faultActor:
 faultNode:
 faultDetail:
        {}:return code:  405
No service point is mapped to the request.
        {http://xml.apache.org/axis/}HttpErrorCode:405

(405)The service method invoked requires an optional capability not supported by the repository.
        at org.apache.axis.transport.http.HTTPSender.readFromSocket(HTTPSender.java:744)
```

Any clues.

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint does not implement the entire CMIS spec. Found this article while finding answers for my SharePoint dotCMIS issues, perhaps you might this useful.

> ...the point is that Sharepoint does not follow the spec 100% ... while you can create a custom mechanism to use some aspects of Sharepoint via CMIS, I highly doubt you can get it to function 100% the way we need it to function via the Documents and Media portlet. This is why we had to write a custom implementation that is a hybrid of CMIS + MS WebServices. Our OOTB solution for 6.1 CE will not work. You need to use 6.1 EE + the **Sharepoint hook**.

source - https://www.liferay.com/community/forums/-/message_boards/view_message/17403852